# Splicing F# lists

Tags: list, f#

What's the best way to splice one list into the middle of another in F#?

For example, suppose the lists are `[1; 2; 3; 4]` and `[7; 8; 9]` respectively, and the splicing point is halfway along the first list, the result should be `[1; 2; 7; 8; 9; 3; 4]`.

By 'best' I mean simplest/most idiomatic, on condition that it takes time no more than linear in the length of the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use the built in [List.insertManyAt](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#insertManyAt) - no need to invent anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already on [F# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-6#additional-collection-functions), I would indeed follow Jackson's advice and just use the newly introduced [List.insertManyAt](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#insertManyAt).

If you're still on an older version and if you're fine with exceptions when the index is out of bounds, you could go with something like:

```
let insertManyAt index newValues source =
    let l1, l2 = List.splitAt index source
    l1 @ newValues @ l2
```

Or if you want a total function:

```
let insertManyAt index newValues source =
    if List.length source < index
    then
        None
    else
        let l1, l2 = List.splitAt index source
        Some (l1 @ newValues @ l2)
```

Answer (score 2):

An illustration how to solve the problem of inserting one list into another at an arbitrary position as a recursive function:

```
let insertManyAt index values source =
    let rec aux acc n =
        if n < index then function                       // not reached index yet
            | xs, y::ys -> aux (y::acc) (n + 1) (xs, ys) // element from source
            | _, [] -> List.rev acc                      // source exhausted, done
        else function
            | x::xs, ys -> aux (x::acc) n (xs, ys)       // element from values
            | [], y::ys -> aux (y::acc) n ([], ys)       // values empty, take source instead
            | [], [] -> List.rev acc                     // both lists empty, done
    aux [] 0 (values, source)

[ 0; 1; 2 ]
|> insertManyAt 1 [ 8; 9 ]
// val it : int list = [0; 8; 9; 1; 2]
```